# How to keep object reference like Task when reloading ViewModel by using Navigation?

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

**Navigation:** Everytime I click a menu item, `NavView_Navigate` is invoked from my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` and the `<Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" IsTabStop="True"/>` inside MainWindow is loaded with the View/Page. Inside the Page I have my ViewModel instance through `ViewModel = App.Current.Services.GetService<ObjectViewModel>();`.

The ViewModel contains a `Task? task;` and with the button `void Start()` I start my script and does the following:

```
token = cts.Token;
task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    _service.Run(SelectedBusinessCentral);
}, token);
```

I also have a `void Stop()` to stop the running Task and keep things asynchronous, through:

```
if (task != null)
{
    _service?.Stop();
    if (!task.IsCompleted)
    {
       cts?.Cancel();
    }
}
```

When I switch menu items, I lose all memory references in my ViewModel and cannot use `Stop()` anymore because somehow the `Task = null`. I get what happens but I don't know how I should solve that the Task reference is decoupled from reloading the ViewModel when using the navigation menu.

**Question:** How do I stop losing my reference to the `Task` instance when my navigation reloads the ViewModel?

**ViewModel**

```
private readonly RobotService _service;

CancellationTokenSource? cts;
CancellationToken token;
Task? task;

public RobotViewModel(RobotService service)
{
    _service = service;
}

public void Start()
{
    if (SelectedObject != null)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        token = cts.Token;
        {
            token = cts.Token;
            task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _service.Run(SelectedObject);
            }, token);
        }
    }
}

public void Stop()
{
    if (task != null)
    {
        _service?.Stop();
        if (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            cts?.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

**Registration**

```
    services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();

    services.AddSingleton<HomePage>();
    services.AddSingleton<BedrijfseenheidPage>();
    services.AddSingleton<SmtpPage>();
    services.AddSingleton<RobotPage>();

    services.AddTransient<BedrijfseenheidViewModel>();
    services.AddTransient<SmtpViewModel>();
    services.AddTransient<RobotViewModel>();
```

**ChatGTP** has some knowledge, would like to know a good strategy from a best practice by someone?

> In a WinUI app, it's common to lose reference to objects, including Task instances, when you navigate between pages or reload a ViewModel. This is because each time you navigate to a page, a new instance of the ViewModel might be created, leading to a loss of state and references to previously created objects.

> To maintain a reference to an object in your ViewModel across page navigation or ViewModel reloads, you can consider using one of the following strategies:

Comment: Have you tried making the `Task` and `CancellationTokenSource` `static` members of the view model?

Comment: Can you post code around how you are registering your ViewModels as services?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride static is not the solution, I tried

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AddSingleton` in this case. `AddTransient`, to quote the docs:

> Specifies that a new instance of the service will be created every time it is requested.

Comment: Thanks, it's correct. Changed to Singleton and now I can switch menu's and still kill the Task by using Stop().